# What program in javascript can be written to solve the sum: 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3....+100^100

Tags: javascript

```
let sum = 0;
for ( let i = 0; i<100 ; i++){
  sum = sum + i^i;
}
console.log(sum);
```

I have tried this and it isn't working. Can anyone please help?

Comment: The `^` symbol doesn't do what you're expecting in JavaScript - you need to use `Math.pow()`

Comment: Seriously, you should start by looking for how to compute powers in javascript instead of dumping your raw question.

Comment: Yea i know. I'm sorry

Answer (score 2):

With ES6, you could use `**` for power, otherwise use [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).

`^` denotes in Javascript a [bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR) operator.

```js
let sum = 0; 

for ( let i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
   sum += i ** i;
} 

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Let's precise that IE and Edge don't support it. Code written for browsers should just use `Math.pow`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
sum = sum + Math.pow(i, i);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made the correction and it worked. Really appreciate the help